# How to Pass HTML Content in Bootstrap 3 Popover Through data-content Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/LC8opsCXgR)**

I know we can pass HTML content in Bootstrap Popover by JavaScript but just wondering if there is a way to pass content through `data-content` without using JavaScript something like:

```
var ecoloInfoTable = "<strong>Yes This is Data</strong>";
var data = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="'+ecoloInfoTable+'"> <i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>';
 $(".container").append(data);
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

Thanks

Comment: `data-html="true" data-content="<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="'+ecoloInfoTable+'"> <i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option that enables HTML content in popover. This option can be passed via JavaScript e.g.

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({ html: true });
```

or in HTML (*which is what you are asking*) e.g.

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="In this title I have <b>bold</b> text" data-html="true"> 
    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<script>
   // Initializing popover without options
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
</script>
```

As you can see in [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/a847bhwZlW), you can have HTML inside the `title` attribute and it an be shown properly in the popover.